# Working with Vertx JsonArray and RxJava Observables

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x, vertx-verticle

A vertx `JsonObject` contains a vertx `JsonArray`, similar to:

```
{
 "myArray":[
   {"id":"1", name:"Yael" },
   {"id":"2", name:"Haddasa"}
 ]
}
```

What is the correct way to create an RxJava `Observable` using the array, so that the observable will handle each element in the array separately. Have tried the following:

```
JsonArray vertxJsonArray = h.getJsonArray("myArray");
Observable<Object> observable = Observable.fromArray(vertxJsonArray);
observable.flatMapSingle(s -> {
   ...
```

But using the above, the array is not split up into separate elements.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `JsonArray` implements `Iterable`, you can use [Observable.fromIterable()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#fromIterable-java.lang.Iterable-), like so:

```
@Test
public void from_iterable_test() {
    final TestObserver<Object> testObserver = new TestObserver<>();

    final String json = "{\"myArray\": [{\"id\": \"1\", \"name\": \"Yael\"}, {\"id\": \"2\", \"name\": \"Haddasa\"}] }";

    final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(json);

    final JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJsonArray("myArray");

    Observable.fromIterable(jsonArray).subscribe(testObserver);

    assertEquals(jsonArray.size(), testObserver.valueCount());
}
```